# EJS File displaying date incorrectly (day is one behind)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, ejs

I have an ejs file displaying a date that is coming from my node server and mongoose database.  In the server and database, the date is correct, I set a console.log for the date, and it returns:

```
2020-06-10T00:00:00.000Z
```

June 10th, as expected.  However, when I have it display in the ejs file, it displays as June 9th:

```
<p><%= ticket.due_date.toDateString() %></p>
```

and it displays on the page as

```
Tue Jun 09 2020
```

This also seems to be a problem when I use moment to refactor the date format for sending to the ejs file:

```
        console.log(ticket.due_date);
        date = moment(ticket.due_date).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
        console.log(date);
```

and this outputs into the console as:

```
2020-06-10T00:00:00.000Z
2020-06-09
```

Is there some formatting issue I am missing, or is it inherent with the system and if so, how do I simply add a day in the ejs file to make it correct?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Date` is not a string; it's an object that encapsulates a moment in time (internally, a big number). It doesn't carry any other interesting details like how the string you used to create it was originally formatted. So when you output a `Date`  with `.toDateString()`, will simply output a string for the timestamp according to the JavaScript spec for [`.toDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString).

There are numerous valid ways to format a `Date` as a string. I'd look through the docs on [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). For example, one option is [`.toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) which seems to be the format you're expecting. If you want to output user-friendly dates in a multitude of formats, you'll need to look to libraries like [`Moment.js`](https://momentjs.com/).

**Update**:

You seem to be working with a misconception about dates. An ISO 8601 date like the example `2020-06-10T00:00:00.000Z` means midnight UTC (a.k.a. GMT, Zulu, etc). a `Date` doesn't represent a local calendar date, it represents a moment in time, specifically the number of milliseconds since 1 January, 1970, UTC. This means when you deal with JavaScript dates, you should be intentional to construct them with the appropriate understanding that they represent a moment in time. For example, if you want a date to reflect midnight in your local time zone, you can use the constructor:

```
const date = new Date(2020, 5, 10);
```

...and when you output the date, you should remember that the person viewing the moment in time may be in a different time zone, so the date may not reflect as the exact same thing.

If you're wanting to deal with a calendar date instead of a timestamp (which would have been a better name for `Date`), then you can use UTC dates throughout and make sure when you output strings that you specify you want to format the date using the UTC time offset. Alternately, you might want to stick with strings if you don't want any of the semantics of timestamps.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation.  I still seem to have an issue with converting.  According to the docs, there are two ways I can convert the date, using toDateString() like I was trying (this inputs the day before) and now I tried using toISOString() like you mentioned, and that outputs as 2020-06-25T00:00:00.000Z, which is correct, but not visually friendly.  It seems that some of the date conversion functions are correct, while others are not.

Comment: I also used moment to convert it before sending to the server with the same incorrect results: date = moment(ticket.due_date).format("YYYY-MM-DD");  before conversion, the console logs the correct date, but after the conversion, it is a day behind, just like it is elsewhere.  I am not sure if there is a better format I should use or if I should just add a day when I do all of these conversions.

Comment: The date conversions are correct; you're just operating under a misconception. Your date is at midnight UTC; it's outputting "the day before" because that's the date it would be at the exact same moment of time but in your local time zone. If you want the date to represent 2020-06-25 at midnight in your local timezone, create it with `new Date(2020, 5, 25)`.

Comment: (the `Z` in the date output indicates UTC, by the way)

Comment: Oh, this all makes sense, thank you.  I assume ideally it would be best for server to store UTC information, and then convert it to local when showing it in a page, so I think I would like to stick with using a timestamp.  I saw that toLocaleDateString is supposed to convert UTC time to local time, however, even this is displaying a day before, both on the server and the front-end, so I am unsure if there is another method to converting a date to local time; I had thought this would be it.

Comment: `toLocaleDateString` doesn't shift the timestamp of the Date before outputting the string. It displays what the local date/time would be at the timestamp represented by the Date.

Comment: Oh, I see, that makes sense that it would do that.  So, in theory, when creating the timestamp in the first place, I should convert it from local time to UTC time; is this the best way to do it?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do. If you want a date that represents a moment of time in your local time zone, you should create the date in your timezone. If you want a value representing a calendar date (not a moment in time) you can create it in UTC and always output it using UTC as well.

Comment: Yep, sounds about right. Alternatively, you could convert the string the user entered to Date on the client and send the full timestamp to the server. That way the date the user _meant_ will match the date being _stored_.

Comment: Interesting, thank you for all of your help.  This all seems very confusing, also because I have a date_created portion that is automatically put in as Date.now, so alternatively, this should be converted the other way when presented on the front end.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help!  Simply using moment(ticket.due_date) automatically does the conversion on the server side for me.